# Implement HTTP server using libevent

Tags: c++, http, c++17, server

```
#include "fmt/format.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <event2/event-config.h>
#include <event2/util.h>
#include <evhttp.h>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
auto
main() -> int
{
    constexpr char host[] = "127.0.0.1";
    std::uint16_t port = 5555;

    using event_base_new_type
        = std::pointer_traits<decltype(event_base_new())>::element_type;
    using event_base_deleter_type = decltype(&event_base_free);
    auto event_base
        = std::unique_ptr<event_base_new_type, event_base_deleter_type>(
            event_base_new(), &event_base_free);

    if(!(event_base))
    {
        fmt::print(stderr, "Failed to init libevent.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    using evhttp_new_type
        = std::pointer_traits<decltype(evhttp_new(event_base.get()))>::element_type;
    using evhttp_deleter_type = decltype(&evhttp_free);
    auto http = std::unique_ptr<evhttp_new_type, evhttp_deleter_type>(evhttp_new(event_base.get()), &evhttp_free);

    auto handle = evhttp_bind_socket_with_handle(http.get(), host, port);
    if(!handle)
    {
        fmt::print(stderr, "Failed to init http server.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    auto callback = [](evhttp_request* req, void*) {
        auto* OutBuf = evhttp_request_get_output_buffer(req);
        if(!OutBuf)
            return;
        evbuffer_add_printf(OutBuf,
            "<html><body><center><h1>Hello World!</h1></center></body></html>");
        evhttp_send_reply(req, HTTP_OK, "", OutBuf);
    };
    evhttp_set_gencb(http.get(), callback, nullptr);
    if(event_base_dispatch(event_base.get()) == -1)
    {
        fmt::print(stderr, "Failed to run messahe loop.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Compile

```
g++ a.cpp -lfmt -levent
```

### Run

```
$ ./a.out
$ ab -c 1000 -k -r -t 10 http://127.0.0.1:5555/
```

Open `http://127.0.0.1:5555/` in browser

What I want to know:

- Is my `unique_ptr` necessary? valgrind reports no memory leak even though I don't use `unique_ptr` nor free manually.
- more elegant/correct code.

Comment: https://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/05/26/c-plus-plus-wrapper-for-socket/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Not too much to review as the code uses `evhttp` to handle HTTP and provide a basic, static reply for each request.

Why is `host` `constexpr`, but not the `port`?

All those `using` statements, combined with traits and `decltype` one after the other makes the code very hard to read, almost obscuring the fact that `evhttp` is being initialized at that point. I would try to rewrite that part in a simpler way.

Why `auto main() -> int` instead of the simple, classic `int main()`?